# Android - Espresso testing - How to take a screenshot which would be shown on Testdroid result?

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, testdroid

I'm using the [**Espresso**](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html)-framework for my Android testing and additionally I'm using the [**Testdroid-Cloud**](http://testdroid.com/) for automatic testing on real devices.

Does anybody know, how to tell **Espresso** to make a screenshot, which is shown on the Testdroid Dashboard?

If I disable **Espresso**, the **Testdroid** crawler automatically make screenshots. By uing the **Espresso**-framework it doesn't! See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I've found a [description](http://instantdevices.com/tech/tips-and-tricks-taking-screenshots-with-espresso-or-espresso-v2-0), but why I need the _"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>"_ permission?
The auto Testdroid crawler makes screenshots without this permission!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as I know `Testdroid Crawler` is an instrumentation testing tool similar to Google's `monkey UI/Application Exerciser` based on `Appium` testing framework.

> The auto Testdroid crawler makes screenshots without this permission!

You're wrong. All necessary system permissions are provided by `adb`(`Android Debug Bridge`) or `appium` script at app runtime. Notice, that you don't see `Crawler` implementation, just the results.

> Does anybody know, how to tell Espresso to make a screenshot, which is
>   shown on the Testdroid Dashboard?

Here'a a quick tutorial how to do it using your own custom Espresso method: http://testdroid.com/tech/tips-and-tricks-taking-screenshots-with-espresso-or-espresso-v2-0

Remember of adding this line to `AndroidMainfest.xml`:

Another possibility is to use `Spoon` along with `Espresso`. The test would looks like then:

```
   @Test
    public void checkIfSettingsMenuItemsAreVisible() throws InterruptedException {
        //open OptionsMenu to see available items
        openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(mRule.getActivity());
        //create a screenshot with 'options_menu' TAG
        Spoon.screenshot(mRule.getActivity(), "options_menu");
        //check if Settings item is Visible
        onView(withText(R.string.action_settings)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        //check if `Sort` item is Visible
        onView(withText(R.string.action_sort)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        //perform click on `Sort` OptionsMenu item
        onView(withText(R.string.action_sort)).perform(click());
        //create a screenshot with 'options_menu_sort' TAG
        Spoon.screenshot(mRule.getActivity(), "options_menu_sort");
        //check if `Sort -> By Value id` item is Visible
        onView(withText(R.string.menu_sort_length)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        //check if `Sort -> By Joke length` item is Visible
        onView(withText(R.string.menu_sort_a_z)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
```

Please check official `Spoon` site: http://square.github.io/spoon/

and this article: http://elekslabs.com/2014/05/creating-test-reports-for-android-with-spoon-and-emma.html

Hope it will help

Comment: Thx for the answer!
Do you've an idea how to capture videos?